# Чи є множина для слова сум?

Tags: вживання-слів, правопис, словники, число

Чи є множина для слова сум? В деяких словниках, наприклад тут
[https://slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=сум](https://slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC)
пишуть, що є, в інших немає. А як насправді?

Answer (score 9):

Припускаю, споглядалисте лише на таблицї — що тут, що нп. від [словника УМІФ-а](//lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/). Основна проблема таких таблиць, же вони переважно заповнені автоматично і з поверхневою перевіркою.

Якщо мова про тлум, то згаданий Словник.ua тупо бере з [СУМ11](http://sum.in.ua/s/sum), котрий робився руками, а отже більше довіри, там ж можна побачити приклад (навмисно повернуто до віршового вигляду) від [Грінченка](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%96_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F,_%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%97_(%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE)):

> Ні поля, ні гаї,
> Ні пташки щебетливі
> Не приспали мої
> *Суми* — болі вразливі.

Тож, питаннє можна вважати закритим: **множина існує**. [СУМ20](http://sum20ua.com/) поки не покриває слова на **с**, тож як буде і не забуду — оновлю відповідь. Але про всяк можна також спробувати довести через узус, тобто вжив. З неприємного, чимало слів мають пня *сум* — місто *Суми*, *сума* як торба, *сума* як загал ітд. Можна подумати, же вони жїночого роду, отже проблема вирїшена, бо хоч множина і майже однакова для всїх родів, але можна зачепитися за родовий відмінок, бо є ріжниця: *сумів* проти *сум*. Але, насправдї, множина може бути [однаковою](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0#178039) повністю, особливо для декотрих говірок, тому *сумів* може бути і жїночого роду, тож покладаємося на вміст. Ще одна проблема, котру помітив для себе — *сумів* чомусь часто буває виплодом одруківки від *сумнів*, але тут теж відносно легко зрозуміти з вмісту. За джерело беру корпус [Лайпциґа](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B2).

> - Нехай цей рік тримає тебе, від усіх негараздів, **сумів** і напастей, і дарує всім навколо, і нам з тобою, надію і мрію, любов і щастя! *(u-news.org.ua, collected on 13/06/2012)*
> - Нехай цей рік зберігає тебе, від всіх негод, **сумів** і напастей, і дарує всім навколо, і нам з тобою, надію й мрію, любов і щастя! *(aback.org.ua, collected on 13/06/2012)*
> - Чернець не вільний від **сумів** і турбот великого християнського світу; цьому світу він дарує свої почуття й ідеї, породжені самотою і спокоєм. *(nach.com.ua, collected on 04/04/2014)*
> - Сидячи на руках або бродячи по кімнатах, воно часто шукає захисту в матері, у няньки, у всіх дорослих від своїх дитячих страхів, **сумів** і засмучень. *(posmishka.org, collected on 13/06/2012)*
> - Кожний його вірш - це ціла гама вражень, думок, радостей і **сумів**. *(vezet.biz.ua, collected on 02/04/2014)*
> - Того, хто позбавить мусульманина від суму, Аллах позбавить від одного з **сумів** Судного дню, а хто приховає недоліки мусульманина, Аллах приховає недоліки у Судний день». *(kamenka-3.nadybat.com.ua, collected on 07/04/2014)*

Ітд. Щоправда, відносно малий вжиток, але він є, отже теж можна зробити висновок, що **множина існує**.